# How can I count unique values and groupby?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have been trying to count and group per row the number of unique values. Perhaps will be easier to explain showing a table. I should first transpose before counting and groupby??

| Box1 | Box2 | Box3 | Count Result 1 | Count Result 2 | Count Result 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Data A | Data A | Data B | Data A = 2 | Data B = 1 |  |
| Data C | Data D | Data B | Data C = 1 | Data D = 1 | Data B = 1 |

Comment: Data A = 2 is the exact output you seek? or just a number?

Comment: Could be just a number. I'm seeking for the total count of each Data per row.

Answer (score 1):

in GS try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(
 QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:C3&" = ×"&ROW(A2:C3)), "×"), 
 "select max(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2")&
 QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:C3&" = ×"&ROW(A2:C3)), "×"), 
 "select count(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2")&"​", 
 "offset 1", ),,9^9)), "​")))
```

[image]